# Pull data from database to put in line graph achartengine

Tags: android, sqlite, bar-chart, achartengine

I want to display my data from db to bar graph (Achartengine), I have two fields date and bmi result. Date is in string format and bmi is in double/int.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
public class BMICalculatorDB {
public static final String KEY_BMIID = "bmi_id";
public static final String KEY_BMIDATA = "bmi_data";
public static final String KEY_BMIDATE = "bmi_date";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DB_bmi";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tbl_bmi";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DBHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_BMIID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_BMIDATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_BMIDATE + " TEXT NOT NULL );"
                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL( "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE );
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public BMICalculatorDB(Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

public BMICalculatorDB open(){
    ourHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry( String data, String date ) {
    //, String date 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_BMIDATA, data);
    cv.put(KEY_BMIDATE, date);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public String getBMIID() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] column =
            new String[]{ KEY_BMIID };
    Cursor c = 
            ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null);

    String result = "";
    int iID = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BMIID);

    for ( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
        result = result + c.getString(iID);
    }

    return result;
}

public String getBMIDataData(){

    String[] column =
                new String[]{ KEY_BMIDATA };
        Cursor c = 
                ourDatabase.query( DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null );

        String result = "";
        int iData = c.getColumnIndex( KEY_BMIDATA );

        for ( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
            result = result + c.getString( iData );
        }


    return result;
}

public String getBMIDateData(){
    String[] column =
            new String[]{ KEY_BMIDATE };
    Cursor c = 
            ourDatabase.query( DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null );

    String result = "";
    int iDate = c.getColumnIndex( KEY_BMIDATE);

    for ( c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ){
        result = result + c.getString( iDate );
    }


return result;
}

public void updateEntry( long lId, String mData, String mDate ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();

    cvUpdate.put( KEY_BMIDATA, mData );
    cvUpdate.put( KEY_BMIDATE, mDate );
    ourDatabase.update( DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_BMIID + " = lId", null );
}

public String getData(long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public String getDate(long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset(String title) {

    String[] column =
            new String[]{ KEY_BMIDATA };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query( DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null );

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Line1");
    TimeSeries series2 = new TimeSeries(title);

    getBMIDataData();

    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        int date = c.getInt((Integer) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("bmi_date"));
        int weight = c.getInt((Integer) c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("bmi_data"));
        series2.add(weight, date);
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    c.close();

    dataset.addSeries(series);
    dataset.addSeries(series2);

    return dataset;
}


public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

    //Lager TimeSeries for den første linja
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = getDemoDataset("Line1");

    //Kode for render
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    //Optimalisering linje1
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    renderer.setFillPoints(true);

    // Optimalisering linje2 husk rekke følgen
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer2.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
    renderer2.setFillPoints(true);

    //Legger til render seriene
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

    //Optimalisering grafen
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("Test");
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Dager");
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);

    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);


    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, 
            mRenderer, "Line Graph Title");

    return intent;

}
```

}

But I got errors in line 28:

```
Cursor c = dbSqlite.query( DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null );
```

and

```
XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = getDemoDataset("Line1");
```

I'm really stuck with this. any help is truly appreciated.

The errors:

```
11-11 02:33:06.542: E/AndroidRuntime(344): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 02:33:06.542: E/AndroidRuntime(344): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 02:33:06.542: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
11-11 02:33:06.542: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at com.fps.iHealthFirst.calculators.LineGraph.getDemoDataset(LineGraph.java:53)
11-11 02:33:06.542: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at com.fps.iHealthFirst.calculators.LineGraph.getIntent(LineGraph.java:87)
11-11 02:33:06.542: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at com.fps.iHealthFirst.calculators.BMICalculator.onClick(BMICalculator.java:181)
11-11 02:33:06.542: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
11-11 02:33:06.542: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-11 02:33:06.542: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-11 02:33:06.542: E/AndroidRuntime(344):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

Comment: Post the errors, so I can see what is happening.

Comment: I've put together my code in the BMICalculatorDB but I still got the same NPE error. can you tell me what I'm missing? I believe it's not null

Comment: it looks like upon calling your getIntent method, which in turn calls the getDemoSet method, which in turn calls the getWritableDatabase method is having trouble with the last mentioned call. from here i can't see how you're making these calls in your activity, but a simple solution for now is to change change the cursor in the getDemoDataset from `Cursor c = ourDatabase.query( DATAB...` to `Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().query( DATAB...` if it works then we at least know where to look.

Comment: @mango hello i changed my cursor to this: Cursor c = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase().query( DATABASE_TABLE, column, null, null, null, null, null ); but i still got nullpointerexception..

Comment: no, remove `"ourDatabase."` try the above first.

Comment: When I tried to remove ourDatabase let it just Cursor c = getWritableDatabase().query( DATAB... I got error. ? Thanks @mango for helping I really need to display the data on graph..

Comment: Was it a different error? Are you opening your database correctly before you call your method? What context are you using when you instantiate it?

Comment: please check my whole code here: http://pastebin.com/Zq0GQCNL I'm really stuck with this error

Comment: Hey did you solve your error??

Comment: can you please post your code. i executed your code http://pastebin.com/Zq0GQCNL it didnt work.

Comment: @user1844638 give ur email. thanks

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes could you also tell me how you solved your error? I am making something similar, thank you.